# How to generate point in 2D uniformly distributed on a rectangle?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried to generate a 1000 points in 2D uniformly distributed on a rectangle of dimensions [-1,1]x[0,0.5], then plot the points, but I couldn't. I get this error.

```
typeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.
```

Here is the code I came up with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
vect = np.random.uniform(1000)
plt.plot(range(-1,1), range(0,0.5), vect)
plt.show()
```

I think I don't really understand how to do it. Should I use `np.random.randn` or `np.random.rand`? I would have to have some explanations about what I did wrong. (if possible to each line so that i can better understand)

Thank you

Comment: What is your expected output @Maestra?

Comment: I should show a plot of the points

Answer (score 1):

first: `xlist = np.random.uniform(1000,low=-1, high = 1)`
second `ylist = np.random.uniform(1000,low=0, high = 0.5)`
last   `plt.scatter(xlist, ylist)`

Comment: Are you sure Does it generate points? I would suggest `plt.scatter` instead of `plt.plot` if he is looking for points

Comment: @Karthik Yes, of course you are right - `plt.scatter`.

Comment: I get this error msf File "<ipython-input-4-34f1399773c6>", line 1
    xlist = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, 1000).
                                              ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument.

Comment: @Maestra fixed. But you know, you could have fixed the syntax yourself.

Comment: Yes I did. I deleted "low=" and "high=" and it worked. The code I finally used was: First, xlist = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 1000). Second, ylist = np.random.uniform(0, 0.5, 1000). Last,  plt.scatter(xlist, ylist). The structure is different from yours but I guess both work. Thanks for you help.